# Debugging closures in javascript

Tags: javascript, debugging, closures

When I try to debug the javascript code which has a lot of closures I use to put a breakpoints.

Then I go to see the stack but most of the times I just see a call stack full of anonymous functions which is a nightmare for me.

What is the best way to debug closure in javascript?

Comment: it depends completely on what the problem is...can you be more specific?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, in Google Chrome, you can see variables content throughout closures:

[image]

Local is the current execution context
Closure is its enclosing execution context
...
Up to the global execution context

Answer (score 5):

You can add a name to the callback function. That way the function name will be shown during debugging.

As an example in jQuery

```
$('div').each( function divLoop() {
  ..
});
```

In OOP Javascript, it's common to call the function as the name of the method

```
MyClass.prototype.methodName = function methodName() { ... }
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of providing anonymous functions as your callback, try declaring a function and use that instead.

http://jsfiddle.net/v9Fas/

This way you can debug inside of the callback function just like a normal function call.